# Android: OnItemClickListener not working the way I expected

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I wrote a code that responds to the list view's item click. I intended that the clicked item on the list would return the URI of the media source through the `Toast` message, and start playing.

Here is the code.

```
lvAlarmTones.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
        ringtone = ringtoneSources.get(position);
        Uri toneUri = Uri.parse(ringtone);
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(ChooseAlarmToneActivity.this, toneUri);
            mediaPlayer.start();
            Log.i(ApplicationManager.LOG, "Media loaded: " + ringtone);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(ChooseAlarmToneActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        Toast.makeText(ChooseAlarmToneActivity.this, ringtone, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

When I run this code, I manage to successfully get the `Toast` with the URI, but I still fail to have the media played.

Comment: instead of creating everytime mediaPlayer, create one as global and use it for every item click. try put the toast inside the try block end. and run again

Comment: @Ahamed All right, I changed the code the you said. But I still fail to play the media.

Comment: have you got any LogCat error. please kindly post if yes.

Comment: @Ahamed In which part do you think will be ideal to insert `Log` in that code?

Comment: dear, i am asking about Logcat error or exception. not Log. i am giving you one suggestion, get one mp3 file and add it on raw folder in your res folder. and then try to play that raw MP3 like mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song); Uri is the problem if the song play well

Comment: @MarshallS.Lee you forget to call prepare() before start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by modifying the code as follows.

```
    lvAlarmTones.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            ringtone = ringtoneSources.get(position);
            Uri toneUri = Uri.parse(ringtone);

            if(mediaPlayer != null) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.release();
            }
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(ChooseAlarmToneActivity.this, toneUri);
            mediaPlayer.start();
            Toast.makeText(ChooseAlarmToneActivity.this, ringtone, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's means your click listener not have any issue but something wrong in media player code execution.

```
 mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(ChooseAlarmToneActivity.this, toneUri);
                mediaPlayer.start();
                Log.i(ApplicationManager.LOG, "Media loaded: " + ringtone);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(ChooseAlarmToneActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Check your catch exception you will find an error and I strongly recommended to handle error use [OnErrorListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener.html)